Update existing cloud watch group
Update existing cloud watch group for aws . Tired import , data but not updating existing cloud watch group. Anyone have this problem ? End goal to update amazon mq cloud Watch general group with kms. terraform verison 1.5

Add your terraform resource definition to the question, and what happens when you attempt the terraform apply.

I dont find even solution to work so didnt reach that apply job
